# Create Order programmatically with tablerates

Tags: magento2, table-rates, create-order

I'm trying to place an order programmatically with tablerates.
Here is my code

```
 $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($postData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($postData['billing_address']);

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $shippingAddress */
        $shippingAddress= $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress
            ->removeAllShippingRates()
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway') //shipping method
            ->setShippingDescription('Table Rate - Best Way');

        $this->handlePayment('banktransfer');
        $quote->setPayment($this->payment);
        $quote->setCheckoutMethod(QuoteManagement::METHOD_GUEST);
        $quote->save();

        $quote->collectTotals();
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($quote->getId());
        $order = $this->orderResource->load($this->order, $orderId);
```

I'm constantly getting `Please specify a shipping method.` Regardless what I try. In `QuoteValidator` it tries to get the rate `$rate = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($method);`  which always returns false. tablerates is setup

how can I place this order with tablerates?

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up on @xhallix's answer: If you use weight-based Table Rate shipping, the shipping rate collection requires the shipping address have a defined `free_method_weight`. This value is calculated during quote total collection, but *not* saved persistently. (There's no such column on `quote_address`.)

In other words:

If you're hitting `Please specify a shipping method` when you know you TableRates should work, it's probably because you need to calculate totals first.

Make sure you run `$quote->collectTotals()` before `$shippingAddress->collectShippingRates()`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem.
If tablerates are configured as `weight -> destination` a `free_method_weight` needs to be set to the shipping address, in order to collect the correct rates

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320495/15474

You need to use this model `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate`