# Magento 2 - create order programmatically with flat rate - No shipping information available

Tags: orders, magento2.3, shipping-methods, programmatically

I tried to create order programmatically with flat rate shipping method with the help of below code. Here, order created successfully but shipping method and rates not apply to order.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore(5);
$storeCode = $store->getCode();
$storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);

$coreSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface');
$coreSession->setIsFailOrder('YES');    //  Biggest patch because we have to create order with archive status and also follow PCI compliance.

$orderData=[
    'currency_id'  => 'USD',
    'email'        => 'helloworld@mageplaza.com', //buyer email id
    'shipping_address' =>[
        'firstname'    => 'John', //address Details
        'lastname'     => 'Doe',
        'street' => '123 Demo',
        'city' => 'Mageplaza',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region' => 43, //'xxx',
        'postcode' => '10019',
        'telephone' => '0123456789',
        'fax' => '32423',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
    ],
   'items'=> [ //array of product which order you want to create
        ['product_id' => '5', 'qty'=> 2]
    ]
];


$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address

if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
    //If not avilable then create this customer 
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
            ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
    $customer->save();
}

$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
$quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
// if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
$customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
$quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

//add items in quote
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
    $product = $product->load($item['product_id']);
    $product->setPrice($product->getPrice());
    $quote->addProduct(
        $product,
        intval($item['qty'])
    );
}

//Set Address to quote
$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

// Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$shippingRate = $objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate');
$shippingRate->setCode('flatrate_flatrate')->getPrice(0);

$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($shippingRate);


$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$rule = $shoppingCartPriceRule->load(9);
$rule->setDiscountAmount('7')->save();
$quote->setCouponCode('amazoncode');

$quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); //payment method
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
$quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

// Set Sales Order Payment
$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

// Collect Totals & Save Quote
$quote->collectTotals()->save();

// Create Order From Quote
$quoteManagement = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement');
$order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote);
$order->setEmailSent(0);

$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setMethod('authorizenet_acceptjs'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
$payment->save();
$order->setState('new');
$order->setStatus('archive');
$order->setEmailSent(0);
$order->save();
$incrementId = $order->getRealOrderId();
$custoemrName = $order->getCustomerName();
$coreSession->unsIsFailOrder();
echo $incrementId;exit;
```

[image]

Please help me  how to assign shipping method and rates to order?

Regards
Hiren Shah

Comment: uspsstandard_uspsstandard shipping method available is your store?

Comment: Yes we created custom shipping method but now you can see updated question which create order with flatrate shipping method but still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please use below code it working fine in my store

https://drops.meetanshi.com/GAWATQ

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$fileFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore(1);
$storeCode = $store->getCode();
$storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);

$coreSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface');
$coreSession->setIsFailOrder('YES');    //  Biggest patch because we have to create order with archive status and also follow PCI compliance.

$orderData = [
    'currency_id' => 'INR',
    'email' => 'helloworld@mageplaza.com', //buyer email id
    'shipping_address' => [
        'firstname' => 'John', //address Details
        'lastname' => 'Doe',
        'street' => '123 Demo',
        'city' => 'Mageplaza',
        'country_id' => 'IN',
        'region' => 544, //'xxx',
        'postcode' => '10019',
        'telephone' => '0123456789',
        'fax' => '32423',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
    ],
    'items' => [ //array of product which order you want to create
        ['product_id' => '1', 'qty' => 2]
    ]
];

try {


    $store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address

    if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
        //If not avilable then create this customer
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
            ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
    }

    $quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
    $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
// if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly
    $customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
    $customer = $customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

//add items in quote
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
        $product = $product->load($item['product_id']);
        $product->setPrice($product->getPrice());
        $quote->addProduct(
            $product,
            intval($item['qty'])
        );
    }

//Set Address to quote
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping ');
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    $quote->save();

// Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

// Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

// Create Order From Quote
    $quoteManagement = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement');
    $order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote);
    $order->setEmailSent(0);

    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setMethod('authorizenet_acceptjs'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
    $payment->save();
    $order->setState('new');
    $order->setStatus('archive');
    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    $order->save();
    $incrementId = $order->getRealOrderId();
    $custoemrName = $order->getCustomerName();
    $coreSession->unsIsFailOrder();
    echo $incrementId;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'error:-  ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the given me whole code with changes. I try to run your code but it will gives me error. **error:- The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.** I have checked the store configuration and flatrate shipping method enable for all stores.

Comment: please clear cache and check ,

Comment: and check that in frontend flatrate shipping method is show or not? , ill also update the shipping address to INDIA you can also change that and check

Comment: my store is in INR so i set the INR and country as INDIA and state set , you need to change that as per your need

Comment: Yes flatrate shipping method display in frontend side.

Comment: still the same error?? and you change the currency code and address as per your store?

Comment: Yes mate. Still facing same error. Also I have changed currency code and store as per my need.

Comment: its working fine in my store dont know what is giong wrong at your end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98223/discussion-between-hiren-shah-and-jigs-parmar).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found that you need to use this model

`$shippingQuoteRate = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate');`

then you need to set the `quote_shipping_rate` parameters. The values can be found in the the database table `quote_shipping_rate`

Here is my complete working:

```
$orderData =[
'currency_id'  => 'USD',
'email'        => trim($email), //buyer email id
'shipping_address' =>[
    'firstname'    => trim($first_name), //address Details
    'lastname'     => trim($last_name),
    'street' => $formattedAddress['address'],
    'city' => $formattedAddress['city'],
    'country_id' => $formattedAddress['country'],
    'region' => $formattedAddress['state'],
    'postcode' => $formattedAddress['zip'],
    'telephone' => trim($phone),
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
],
'items'=> [
    //array of product which order you want to create
    ['product_id'=>$productId,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$productPriceById]
]
];
```

Then here is my method using objectmanager

```
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
  
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();

/**
 * check whether the email address is already registered or not
 */
$customer = $customerFactory->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);
if (!$customer->getId()) {
    try {
        $customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->setEmail($orderData['email']);
        $customer->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname']);
        $customer->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname']);
        $customer->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
  
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        $customAddress = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory')->create();
        $customAddress->setData($orderData['shipping_address'])
                      ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                      ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                      ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        $customAddress->save();  
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($customer->getId());
try {

    $quoteFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory')->create();
    $shippingQuoteRate = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate');
    $quoteFactory->setStore($store);
    $quoteFactory->setCurrency();
    $quoteFactory->assignCustomer($customer);
    foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
        $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->getById($item['product_id']);// get product by product id 
        $quoteFactory->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));  // add products to quote
    }
  
    /*
    * Set Address to quote
    */
    $quoteFactory->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $quoteFactory->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    /*
    * Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
    * You can get this information from the database table `quote_shipping_rate`
    */
    $shippingRateCarrier = 'usps';
    $shippingRateCarrierTitle = 'United States Postal Service';
    $shippingRateCode = 'usps_0_FCP';
    $shippingRateMethod = '0_FCP';
    $shippingRatePrice = '9.95';
    $shippingRateMethodTitle = 'First-Class Package Service - Retail';

    $shippingAddress = $quoteFactory->getShippingAddress();

    $shippingQuoteRate->setCarrier($shippingRateCarrier);
    $shippingQuoteRate->setCarrierTitle($shippingRateCarrierTitle);
    $shippingQuoteRate->setCode($shippingRateCode);
    $shippingQuoteRate->setMethod($shippingRateMethod);
    $shippingQuoteRate->setPrice($shippingRatePrice);
    $shippingQuoteRate->setMethodTitle($shippingRateMethodTitle);

    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod($shippingRateCode); //shipping method
    $quoteFactory->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($shippingQuoteRate);

    $quoteFactory->setPaymentMethod('purchaseorder'); //payment method
    $quoteFactory->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    $quoteFactory->save();

    /*
    * Set Sales Order Payment
    */
    $quoteFactory->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'purchaseorder','po_number' => $orderNo]);

    /*
    * Collect Totals & Save Quote
    */
    $quoteFactory->collectTotals()->save();

    /*
    * Create Order From Quote
    */
    
    $order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement')->submit($quoteFactory);
    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setMethod('purchaseorder'); // Assuming 'purchaseorder' is updated payment method
    $payment->setPoNumber($orderNo);
    $payment->save();
    $order->setState('new');
    $order->setStatus('pending');
    
    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    
    $order->save();

    echo "<br/>Order Created<br/>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hello @Hector Can you please say how to calculate the shipping amount for the table rate dynamic to pass to the shipping address? provide a method for calculating the table rate shipping price for the current quote

Answer (score 0):

Below code works perfectly.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore(5);    //  Set particular store if multi-store available
$storeCode = $store->getCode();
$storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeCode);

$orderData = [
    'currency_id' => 'USD',
    'email' => 'helloworld@mageplaza.com', //buyer email id
    'shipping_address' => [
        'firstname' => 'John', //address Details
        'lastname' => 'Doe',
        'street' => '123 Demo',
        'city' => 'New York',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region' => 43, //'xxx',
        'postcode' => '10001',
        'telephone' => '0123456789',
        'fax' => '32423',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
    ],
    'items' => [ //array of product which order you want to create
        ['product_id' => '1', 'qty' => 2]
    ]
];

try {

    $store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address

    if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
        //If not avilable then create this customer
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
            ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
            ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
    }

    $quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
    $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
    $quote->setStoreId($store->getId());

    $customerRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
    $customer = $customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
        $product = $product->load($item['product_id']);
        $product->setPrice($product->getPrice());
        $quote->addProduct(
            $product,
            intval($item['qty'])
        );
    }

    $billingAddressData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    //Collect shipping rates on quote
    $shippingAddressData->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();

    $shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
    $rule = $shoppingCartPriceRule->load(9);
    $discountamt = 10;  //($discount > 0)?$discount:0;
    $rule->setDiscountAmount($discountamt)->save();
    $quote->setCouponCode('amazoncode');

    $shippingAddressData->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $shippingAddressData->setShippingMethod('uspsstandard_uspsstandard')->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');   //  Custom shipping method same like faltrate_flatrate
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    $quote->save();

    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    $quoteManagement = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement');
    $order = $quoteManagement->submit($quote);
    $order->setEmailSent(0);

    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setMethod('authorizenet_acceptjs'); // Assuming 'test' is updated payment method
    $payment->save();
    $order->setState('new');
    $order->setStatus('archive');
    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    $order->save();
    $incrementId = $order->getRealOrderId();
    $custoemrName = $order->getCustomerName();
    echo $incrementId;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'error:-  ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to do should always be in a command object.

http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/phpunit-magento-command.php

The code like below is really unclean and wrong way to program in magento

```
// This way to code is wrong
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```